# Find duplicated listings in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID, Name, SchoolID, Grade, Major  
1, Alice, School_1, 10, Physics  
2, Bob, School_1, 8, Biology  
3, Alice, School_2, 10, Physics  
4, Alice, School_1, 10, Physics
```

How can I find duplicated listings within each school? (listings in the same school with the same Name, Grade and Major are considered duplicated).

Expected result:

```
ID, Name, SchoolID, Grade, Major, Is_duplicated    
1, Alice, School_1, 10, Physics, Yes  
2, Bob, School_1, 8, Biology, No  
3, Alice, School_2, 10, Physics, No    
4, Alice, School_1, 10, Physics, Yes
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` and `subset` parameter:

```
df['Is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=['Name','Grade','Major','SchoolID'])
print (df)
   ID   Name  SchoolID  Grade    Major  Is_duplicated
0   1  Alice  School_1     10  Physics           True
1   2    Bob  School_1      8  Biology          False
2   3  Alice  School_2     10  Physics          False
3   4  Alice  School_1     10  Physics           True
```

If want `Yes` and `No` add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=['Name','Grade','Major','SchoolID'])
df['Is_duplicated'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
print (df)
   ID   Name  SchoolID  Grade    Major Is_duplicated
0   1  Alice  School_1     10  Physics           Yes
1   2    Bob  School_1      8  Biology            No
2   3  Alice  School_2     10  Physics            No
3   4  Alice  School_1     10  Physics           Yes
```